# beautiful soup find_all() exception

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm using beautiful soup `Data = soup.find_all('td')` which returns to me everything with the tag. is there a way for me to add an exception to not include the tag if `colspan=7`? cause that's the only indicator all the td tags are classless :)

Thank you!

Comment: Iterate over all and skip the ones that have `colspan=7`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if it going works, but you can try it. You should filter first all "td" and after that, filter all collspan=7 . Please try using this:

```
List_One=[]
Data = soup.find_all('td')
for x in Data:
    if not "colspan=7" in x.attrs:
        List_One.append(x)
print(List_One)
```

Comment: `.attrs` is a dictionary, so should be something like `if x.attrs.get('colspan') != '7': `

Answer (score 0):

Instead off `find_all()`, you can use `select()` with the following CSS selector:

```css
td:not([colspan="7"])
```

This will find all `td`'s without `colspan=7`

---

Total test code, using the [w3 colspan html example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
    <body onload="nextHit()">
       <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>January</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>$80</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="7">Sum: $180</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

data = soup.select('td:not([colspan="7"])')

print(data)
```

Output:

```js
[<td>January</td>, <td>$100</td>, <td>February</td>, <td>$80</td>]
```

Comment: Anything missing in my answer @Thekra?